# AWS getSignedUrl expiry in Node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am generating a signed URL for an object in S3 like so:

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  region: "eu-west-2",
  endpoint: "s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com",
  signatureVersion: "v4",
});

s3.getSignedUrl(
  "getObject",
  {
    Bucket: "soliloquy-app",
    Key: key,
    Expires: 30,    // <-- HERE
  },
  (err, url) => {
      return res.status(200).send(url);
  }
);
```

The URL it generates is like so:

https://soliloquy-app.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/iw0EuRb6C4Ab2BFTimomVjEI4HK15FNX.mp3?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAZMWVPARKDIXWFYPM%2F20220830%2Feu-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220830T151912Z&X-Amz-Expires=30&X-Amz-Signature=f8d7490cc2f45cd9e6cdacbe50d9f2da110f4960d86254ab702581d3395d79f9&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host

I actually have 2 problems with this URL:

Firstly, and more importantly it never seems to expire. I passed 30 seconds as the expiry [as per the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrlPromise-property), but the URL seems to be permanently accessible. Why would the expire time be in the URL anyway? Obviously changing it here should not allow you to download it if it did work (which it doesn't), so why have it here?

Secondly, when I put that URL into into the browser, it tries to download it instead of streaming it. Can I set the content type in the GET req?

Comment: When I click on the link I get a message saying it has expired, seems to be working. Just changing the expiration in the url will not work because then the signature does no longer match. No, changing the content type cannot be achieved with that request, for that you would need to change the metadata of the actual object stored in S3.

Comment: Ah! It doesn't allow me to download in a private window, must be cached or something. How silly of me, thanks!

Comment: @luk2302 Your content type was correct too, and it works when I upload it with that metadata. Would you like to upgrade your comment to an answer so I can accept it?